# updating contact name keeps the last contact for a second

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

when I am updating a contact name by the following code it creates new contact out of original contact for couple of seconds and then remove it.

```
String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID+" = ? AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+" = ?";
String[] agrs = {"1",ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, agrs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "googleName")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "googleName")
                .build());
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

(This raw contact comes from google which have a whatsApp number).
***Before performing this update, the tables look like this:-***

***The Raw table***

```
Account type | contact_id | _id
com.google     6            1
com.whatsapp   6            2
```

***contact table:***

```
Display Name | _id    | name_row_contact_id
Lorem          6        1
```

***After rename operation Contact table look like:-***

```
Display Name | _id    | name_row_contact_id
googleName   | 6      | 1
Lorem        | 6      | 2    //---> Why its happening ??
```

***After few seconds from the update operation, this Lorem get removed ***

!!! as this happens, my app thinks that new contact is added and then removed again:( !!!

Am I doing something wrong when I am updating the contact name??

Please help!

Comment: your update code looks ok, this is really weird, a cursor should never be able to return 2 rows with the same unique _id, so I don't see how it's possible your Contacts query can return two contacts with the same ID. can you post your query code for Contacts?

Comment: `
 Cursor cursorContact = context.getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: try printing the entire contact row (you can use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor) and check the difference between the two contacts with _id 6, maybe one of them is marked as dirty/deleted which will signal your app to ignore.
also, which device are you testing this on? have you tried with another device from another manufacturer? some devices may display strange behavior in ContactsContract APIs

Answer (score 0):

I have found cause of the problem and solution.

When I am changing name with row id, obviously it will rename but other mobile applications such as `WhatsApp` have also entry in database where the name is not changed yet. Thats why Edge 7-device create new entry in Contacts table as old name is still present in Data table (used by whatsApp). 
After sometime when WhatsApp do Sync, this old contact get removed.

Solution: Perfect why of renaming is if you rename not by row_id but by contact_id. It will also rename the name of other entries in Data table.

```
    String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
            String[] agrs = {contactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
```